# Construct a Bar Graph with Overlay with data label Using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to add labels in ggplot2 bar graph.

```
ggplot(bank_train, aes(previous_outcome)) +geom_bar(aes(fill = response))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "lightblue"))
```

[image]

Where bank_train is the name of the dataset that has a variable name as previous_outcome. And, response as of (yes or no).

The code above works fine, but I tried to add numbers inside the bar graph, but it gave me an incorrect graph.

Here is my attempt:

```
ggplot(bank_train, aes(previous_outcome)) +geom_bar(aes(fill = response),stat = "identity")
+geom_text(aes(label = count),position = position_stack(vjust= 0.5),
            colour = "white", size = 5)+scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "lightblue"))
```

my problem is understanding the geom_text.

Your help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `after_stat` to get the counts for the `geom_text` label.

```r
set.seed(2022)
n <- 100L
outcomes <- c("failure", "success", "nonexistent")
previous_outcome <- factor(sample(outcomes, n, TRUE), levels = outcomes)
response <- sample(c("yes", "no"))
bank_train <- data.frame(previous_outcome, response)

library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.2.2

ggplot(bank_train, aes(previous_outcome, fill = response)) +
  geom_bar() +
  geom_text(aes(label = after_stat(count)), 
            stat ='count', colour = "white", size = 5,
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "lightblue")) +
  labs(x = 'Previous Outcome', y = 'Count') +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

If the bars are dodged, try `position_dodge2`, like said in comments, and assign half of `after_stat(count)` to the `y` aesthetic.

```r
ggplot(bank_train, aes(previous_outcome, fill = response)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge2") +
  geom_text(aes(label = after_stat(count), y = after_stat(count)/2L), 
            stat ='count', colour = "white", size = 5,
            position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "lightblue")) +
  labs(x = 'Previous Outcome', y = 'Count') +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @Riddle2795 Try `position_dodge2(width = 1)`. But you will have to adjust the vertical placement.

Comment: it didn't work. is this what you mean? `
ggplot(bank_train, aes(previous_outcome, fill = response)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge2") +
  geom_text(aes(label = after_stat(count)), 
            stat ='count', colour = "white", size = 5,
            position_dodge2(width = 1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "lightblue")) +
  labs(x = 'Previous Outcome', y = 'Count') +
  theme_bw()
`

Comment: I have used this method and it works: ` 
ggplot(bank_train, aes(previous_outcome, fill = response)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge2") +
  geom_text(aes(label = after_stat(count)), 
            stat ='count', colour = "red",vjust= -0.2, size = 5,
            position = position_dodge2(width =0.9))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "lightblue")) +
  labs(x = 'Previous Outcome', y = 'Count') +
  theme_bw()` @RuiBarradas thank you!